# Assembly - Why strtol clobbers %rcx register?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

#### Context :

Linux 64.

GCC 4.8.2 (with -O3 -march=native)

The x86_64 abi under my left hand, opened at page 21.

#### The C code :

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

     printf("%d %s\n", atoi(argv[2]),argv[1] );
}
```

#### The assembly code :

(notice that the compiler replaced atoi with strtol by itself)

```
...
    movl    $10, %edx
    movq    16(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    8(%rsi), %rbx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movq    %rbx, %rdx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
...
```

#### The question :

`%rcx` should be reserved for the 4th input integer argument.

`strtol` has 3 input args (respectively registers `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`) and one return, `%eax`.

**Why then is `%rcx` clobbered ?**
This code won't make it :

```
...
    movl    $10, %edx
    movq    16(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    8(%rsi), %rcx <-- look I replaced with %ecx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movq    %rcx, %rdx <-- look I replaced with %ecx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you talking about `strtol()`, when your code calls `atoi()`? Confused, am I.

Comment: The optimizer rather prefer strtol i guess. This is the copy paste. Atoi ran away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each calling convention I know there are some registers that may be modified by the called function and some which must not be modified.

In 32-bit programs ecx may be modified while ebx must not be modified - or, to be more exact - must be re-stored before returning. For 64-bit programs this rule seems to be the same.

Indeed most functions modify most registers; for this reason there is a "popq %rbx" at the end of the code you posted because rbx must not be modified by the function. rcx may be modified and strtol obviously does that!

Comment: Yes but it should not, %rcx is not in the range of inputs/output! So is it that I should relax and say : "that is the way it is" ?

Comment: As Martin said, the calling convention specifies what can be freely modified. The fact that `rcx` is also used for passing arguments doesn't have much to do with it, although that by itself is a good reason for making it caller-saved so that the called function can call other functions easily. See the [ABI docs](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf).

Comment: Yes I already have the abi opened at page 21. Ok so it is the way it works then :) I want to be sure I understand everything since this is the basis. Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: Indeed most calling conventions allow modifying the registers used for input/output arguments. This makes sense because the called functions can call other functions without having to save the registers.

Comment: Yes makes sense Martin. Thanks for that precision. +1